# Show full path name of the ruby file when it get loaded

Tags: ruby

When reading source code, I always want to know the full path of the file when it is loaded, is there any callback method in ruby to accomplish this, or any other way to do this? thanks in advance.

**EDIT** Clarification from the comments:

I want to know where the loaded "somefile" is located while I execute this line: "load somefile"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way I can think of is to patch the `Kernel` module.  According to the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005966) `Kernel::load` searches `$:` for the filename.  We can do the same thing and print the path if we find it.

```
module Kernel
  def load_and_print(string)
    $:.each do |p|
      if File.exists? File.join(p, string)
        puts File.join(p, string)
        break
      end
    end
    load_original(string)
  end

  alias_method :load_original, :load
  alias_method :load, :load_and_print

end
```

We use `alias_method` to store the original `load` method, which we call at the end of ours.

Comment: This is incorrect.  __FILE__ contains the name the script was called as and as such will only contain the full path name if the script was called using the full path name.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Robert. What I want is when the code line "load somefile" is executed, the full path of somefile.rb is printed.

Comment: @Robert, oops you're quite right.  Answer is edited with a correct solution.

Comment: This won't work either; sometimes you will get the right answer, sometimes you will get the wrong answer, sometimes you won't get an answer at all.

Comment: I still don't  quite understand. The __FILE__, as I understand, should be the current file name, not the file I am loading. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: If you are looking for the name of a loaded module, using __FILE__ in the file loading the module isn't going to work.  Also, the Pathname trick will only work if the file exists in the current working directory as that is that the example does, it just prepends the cwd to the filename provided.

Comment: @Robert, Re:"This won't work either": Works for me in OS X, Vista, and Red Hat, using ruby 1.8.6. Would you mind providing a reference or a reliable solution? @eric, perhaps I've misunderstood the question. You want "require 'somefile.rb'" to print the path of 'somefile.rb' to std out?

Comment: @Grodon, yes, I want to know where the loaded somefile.rb is located  while I execute this line: "load somefile".

Comment: @Gordon: It worked for you because your test cases were very limited.  If you don't provide an absolute path to Pathname it will assume it is in your cwd, if it isn't it won't work.  You can easily confirm this by doing "Pathname.new('blah')" and examining the resulting exception.

Comment: I am not aware of a reliable solution (which doesn't mean there isn't one, I haven't researched the question), if I was I would have posted it.

Comment: I made a mistake, the "load" method will load the file with the name exactly same as its input parameter, so the "load somefile" is actually loading file "somefile", not "somefile.rb".

Comment: This will give you wrong results when there is a directory with the same name as the file. For example, if the file is `foo`, which is supposed to load `some_path/foo/some_more_path/foo`, and if you have `some_path` in `$:`, then your script will give the wrong result `some_path/foo`.

Answer (score 16):

## Show a file's pathname in Ruby

How about simple (from a quicky test in [Camping](https://camping.github.io/camping.io/)):

```
File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

?

Answer (score 3):

Gordon Wilson's answer is great, just wanted to add that you can also see *which* libraries were loaded (and their complete path!) , by looking at the output of the variable $" (returns an array of absolute file names)

e.g. the path of the most recently loaded library is at the end of the array

Comment: I'm not getting absolute paths ...   `irb(main):003:0> $"
=> ["enumerator.so", "e2mmap.rb", "irb/init.rb", "irb/workspace.rb", "irb/context.rb", "irb/extend-command.rb", "irb/output-method.rb", "irb/notifier.rb", "irb/slex.rb", "irb/ruby-token.rb", "irb/ruby-lex.rb", "readline.so", "irb/input-method.rb", "irb/locale.rb", "irb.rb"]`

Comment: As of now (Ruby 1.9.3), this answer works and gives the full paths.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious why you're using `load` instead of `require` - in all of my time using Ruby. I've never had occasion to utilize `load`.

Comment: In fact, I asked this question for my code-reading of ZenTest, which include some lines using "load somefile"

Comment: Ah, understood.

If you're looking to learn Ruby via reading, may I suggest Merb? It's got some extremely well documented source code, and follows many best practices. The same can't really be said for ZenTest - after all, Zen<filtered> did write it!

Answer (score 0):

To get the full path of the file, you must assemble a string in the following way (where *yourfileobject* is an object of Ruby's File class).

```
File.expand_path(File.dirname(yourfileobject)) + "/" + yourfileobject.path
```