# Discover the file ruby require method would load?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, irb

The `require` method in ruby will search the lib_path and load the first matching files found if needed. Is there anyway to print the path to the file which would be loaded. I'm looking for, ideally built-in, functionality similar to the `which` command in bash and hoping it can be that simple too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a built-in functionality, but defining your own isn't hard. Here's a solution adapted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456379/show-full-path-name-of-the-ruby-file-when-it-get-loaded):

```
def which(string)
  $:.each do |p|
    if File.exist? File.join(p, string)
      puts File.join(p, string)
      break
    end
  end
end

which 'nokogiri'
#=> /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.1/lib/nokogiri
```

Explanation: `$:` is a pre-defined variable. It's an array of places to search for files you can `load` or `require`. The `which` method iterates through each path looking for the file you called it on. If it finds a match, it returns the file path.

I'm assuming you just want the output to be a single line showing the full filepath of the `required` file, like `which`. If you want to also see the files your `required` file will load itself, something like the solution in the linked question might be more appropriate:

```
module Kernel
  def require_and_print(string)
    $:.each do |p|
      if File.exist? File.join(p, string)
        puts File.join(p, string)
        break
      end
    end
    require_original(string)
  end

  alias_method :require_original, :require
  alias_method :require, :require_and_print

end

require 'nokogiri'
#=>  /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.1/lib/nokogiri
#    /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubygems-update-1.3.5/lib/rbconfig
#    /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.1/lib/nokogiri/xml
#    /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/pp
#    /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/sax
#    /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node
#    /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/xpath
#    /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.1/lib/nokogiri/xslt
#    /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.1/lib/nokogiri/html
#    /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.1/lib/nokogiri/css
#    /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/racc/parser.rb
```

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling I would need to create my own implementation. BTW, this only seems to work with ruby 1.9 because 1.8 doesn't include the individually gem paths explicitly in $:.

Answer (score 1):

$ gem which filename # (no .rb suffix) is what I use...