# How to selectively trace methods and their file access in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

For a Rails app, I would like to overload or modify Kernel::load such that it will print out the full path like `puts "-> #{File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))}/#{File.basename(__FILE__)}"` for each Rails app file that is loaded.

How would I do this?  I would like to further be able to filter, so I am guessing I'd throw a regex on there to be able to only show output (when I don't want it to be grossly verbose) that indicates the access of files within the current rails app root.

At any rate, I'd appreciate an example of overloading this method and where the appropriate place to do this would be active in the Rails app on server start.

**Resolution:**

Well okay after a bit of beating things around and discovering `set_trace_func` I came up with the following:

I integrated `set_trace_fun` into the header of `development.rb` along the lines of what was implemented in the `mtrace` gem.  I had a lot of tweaking to do to filter out everything but my app directory as well as a number of other chatty methods, but it seems to be working out thus far.  The mtrace source that is effectively integrated with modification is as follows:

```
mtrace_indent = 0
set_trace_func lambda {|event, file, line, id, binding, klass|
  case event
  when 'call'
    puts "\e[90m| " * mtrace_indent +
      "\e[35m#{klass}\e[90m#\e[36m#{id} \e[90m#{file}:#{line}\e[0m" +
      "#{'  ' * ([10 - mtrace_indent, 1].max)}\e[90mtxmt://open/?url=file://#{ File.expand_path(file) }&line=#{ line }\e[0m"
    mtrace_indent += 1
  when 'return'
    mtrace_indent -= 1
  end
  mtrace_indent = 0 if mtrace_indent < 0
}
```

Of course the txmt url portions can be removed if you're not on a mac, but that is really quite helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
module Kernel
  alias_method :old_load, :load

  def load filename, wrap = false
    puts "-> #{filename}"
    old_load filename, wrap
  end
end
```

You can put this into `config/initializers`, but that may be a little bit late for what you're trying to do.

Apparently, Rails init process [starts with `config/environment.rb`](http://railsguts.com/initialization.html), so if you put this code at the top of that file, it should be the first thing loaded.

Comment: where do you put that in the rails app?  In the env config so that it only loads for development.rb or elsewhere?

Comment: Where in the stack does this come into play?  I wouldn't mind seeing the rails app stack at startup, but I'm frankly not terribly interested the full rails hierarchy, but more, rather, the dynamics on a per app basis.  ie, the files over which I have control specifically in the app.

Comment: @ylluminate: sorry, didn't get that last comment at all. You have the filename, you can grep and filter it all you want :-)

Comment: tremendous, thank you.  This seems to be early enough I think, however I am interested as to why while regular ruby scripts are showing the desired trace, the views (haml/erb) -- essentially any request to the web app -- are not seemingly using Kernel::load as they are not displaying anything.  Any ideas in this regard as to what method's loading them so that this can be overloaded as well?

Comment: @ylluminate, views will definitely not be loaded with `Kernel#load` or `require`, because their contents are not valid Ruby code. To find out how they are loaded, you can peek into the code for the actionpack gem (one great thing about Ruby -- aside from the odd binary, you can easily access and read the contents of gems). I imagine they would just use `File.read`.

Comment: Yes guys, thanks.  Really getting somewhere now.  I've redefined require and load so far and now looking on to the other ones.  Starting to really get a holistic picture here that's helping already.

Comment: Hey guys, what about using `set_trace_func` in this context?

Comment: @ylluminate: hmm, didn't know about it. Try it out and tell us! :-)

Comment: Okay fellows, I did try it and it worked out very well!  See the edited post above for details.  I think this is doing the trick and is really clarifying a LOT of things so far.

Comment: this saved me. an hour trying to debug a complex set of require statements!