# How to print the filename passed to `require`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When starting the Rails 3.x server (`rails s`), is it possible to print the path and name of each file as it is being loaded?

Something like below, but for every file that is `require`d by Rails (think loading of each railtie, for example):

```
Loading boot.rb...
Loading application.rb...
Loading environment.rb...
Loading development.rb...
Loading routes.rb...
```

Note that I am able to do the above simply by using `puts` calls in the files above, but that is not what I am aiming for. Instead I would like to print the file name being `require`d by any code, not just in my application but whenever `require` is called. For example, printing file names for calls to `require` being made inside the Rails code.

**UPDATE**

Thanks @ScottJShea. I used the following code:

In `application.rb`:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

module Kernel
  def require_and_print(string)
    puts string
    require_original(string)
  end
  alias_method :require_original, :require
  alias_method :require, :require_and_print
end
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you would need to edit kernel.rb. Here is an [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456379/show-full-path-name-of-the-ruby-file-when-it-get-loadedLooks%20like%20you%20would%20need%20to%20edit%20kernel.rb.%20Here%20is%20an%20%5BSO%20Post%5D%5B1%5D%20about%20it) about it where the responder suggests this (although you may ant to limit it to the require method):

```
module Kernel
  def load_and_print(string)
    $:.each do |p|
      if File.exists? File.join(p, string)
        puts File.join(p, string)
        break
      end
    end
    load_original(string)
  end

  alias_method :load_original, :load
  alias_method :load, :load_and_print

end
```

Comment: Super. Used that example for require. Updated answer with the code I used.