# Getting the full path for a required file

Tags: ruby, path

What is the best way to get the full path to a file `file_name` that was successfully `require`-d?

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456379/show-full-path-name-of-the-ruby-file-when-it-get-loaded

Comment: @AshishSaihgal Maybe related, but I am particularly asking for `require`-d files, not `load`-ed files.

Comment: difference between load and require is that you can load a file more than once using load. However if you have required a file then ruby does not load it again when you issue a duplicate require. You can look for loaded files in $LOAD_PATH($:) variable as in the link provided in above comment. And I believe you can list required files by querying $LOADED_FEATURES($")

Comment: @AshishSaihgal I found out the answer while reading one of the answers  you  linked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for loaded files in `$LOAD_PATH` aka `$:` variable as described in [Show full path name of the ruby file when it get loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456379/show-full-path-name-of-the-ruby-file-when-it-get-loaded). And you can list required files by querying `$LOADED_FEATURES` aka `$"`

```
require '/home/ashish/samples/required_test.rb'

$".each do |path|
    puts path
end
```

More info on require - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require

Comment: Easy syntax instead of each loop is `puts $"` after `require`

Answer (score 5):

I figured out the answer. It was `$".last`.